# Error committing transaction using JDBC - Operation Connection.commit is not allowed during a global transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

Am getting the following error when am trying to commit transaction using jdbc from a local ejb
connection.commit();
Oracle database

java.sql.SQLException: DSRA9350E: Operation Connection.commit is not allowed during a global transaction.
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.commit(WSJdbcConnection.java:941)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.bmo.olbb.mostvisitedcount.ejb.MergeAuditRecordsBean.startOperation(MergeAuditRecordsBean.java:89)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.bmo.olbb.mostvisitedcount.ejb.MergeAuditRecordsBean.updatePageCountValues(MergeAuditRecordsBean.java:21)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.bmo.olbb.mostvisitedcount.ejb.EJSLocal0SLMergeAuditRecordsBean_9da6c3b0.updatePageCountValues(EJSLocal0SLMergeAuditRecordsBean_9da6c3b0.java)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.bmo.ctp.test.testEJBservlet.doGet(testEJBservlet.java:51)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1103)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:570)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:486)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3440)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:267)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:815)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1461)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:118)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:458)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:387)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:267)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1037)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:644)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1818)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
[17/11/13 15:33:00:621 EST] 00000029 SystemErr     R    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)

Comment: If your connection is managed by the container, then you probably can't do manual commits.  How is your connection created?

Answer (score 4):

In XA-Datasources->WebSphere Application Server data source properties->WebSphere Application Server data source properties->click Non-transactional data source as True.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is probably using a Container-Managed Transaction or another kind of managed connection. When using managed transactions you are not allowed to `commit()` yourself, as that is handled by the application container (maybe even using a distributed transaction if you are using multiple datasources).

See [Container-Managed Transactions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/transactions003.htm#BNCIJ) in the JavaEE 7 tutorial:

> Enterprise beans that use container-managed transaction demarcation must not use any transaction-management methods that interfere with the container's transaction demarcation boundaries. Examples of such methods are the `commit`, `setAutoCommit`, and `rollback` methods of `java.sql.Connection` or the `commit` and `rollback` methods of `javax.jms.Session`. If you require control over the transaction demarcation, you must use application-managed transaction demarcation.

A `commit()` is done automatically if the method (or chain of methods) completes without an `Exception` (unless an explicit rollback is requested on the context).

Answer (score 0):

One time I had de same problem.
At that time I was using EJB 1.0 and the problem was happening because I did not map the EJB method in Container Transaction Section inside the ejb-jar.xml

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11128666)

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I agree that this is not a high quality answer, but I think there is an answer in here, if he re-writes it explaining how he fixed the problem when he encountered it

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to
   Resources > JDBC > JDBC providers > JDBC_provider > Data sources > data_source > WebSphere Application Server data source properties
2. Check Non-transactional data source property.

Comment: Please follow this link it describes a lot about transaction.https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/configuring_the_message_driven_bean_transaction_support?lang=en

Comment: The above solution to check Non-transactional data source property will work good in your local box but not any environment.